# Web API & Postman - Add Multiple Attachments

Tags: c#, postman, webapi, web-api-testing

Hello All I am not able to upload multiple attachments with postman and I don't understand why
Here there is my Api in order to replace existing files

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/attachments/UpdateMultiple")]
    public Result UpdateMultiple(List<int> id) 
    {
        try
        {
           ATTACHMENT[] results = new ATTACHMENT[] { };
           int position = 0;

            foreach (int i in id)
            {
               
                var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[position];
                ATTACHMENT attachment = entities.ATTACHMENT.Where(a => a.IDATTACHMENT == 
                 i).FirstOrDefault();

                byte[] fileBytes = new byte[] { };

                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.InputStream.CopyTo(ms);
                    fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }

                attachment.Binarydata= fileBytes;
                attachment.TypeFILE = file.ContentType;
                attachment.NAMEFILE = file.FileName;
                entities.SaveChanges();
                
                results[position] = (attachment);
                position++;
            }
            return new Result("OK", results );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            
            return new Result("KO",  + e);
        }
    }
```

Here Postman:
[image]

[image]

Any Suggestion? I have no Idea what to do

Comment: You need to add one more param to the method for the body.

Comment: which param and where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `FromQueryAttribute`/`FromUriAttribute` (depending on the ASP.NET version) to parameter:

```cs
public Result UpdateMultiple([FromQuery] List<int> id)
```

Or

```cs
public Result UpdateMultiple([FromUri] List<int> id)
```

**UPD**

`ATTACHMENT[] results = new ATTACHMENT[] { };` creates an empty array, so accessing it by any index will throw an exception, change it to `var results = new ATTACHMENT[id.Count];`

Comment: It accepts public Result UpdateMultiple([FromUri] List<int> id) but still in error: fileSystem.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Comment: @user18363545 you are creating empty array for results - change it to `var results = new ATTACHMENT[id.Count] ;`

Answer (score 0):

Solved it with help of Guru Stron -thank you!

to fix, I had to add/modify:

```
public Result UpdateMultiple([FromUri] List<int> id){
 List<ATTACHMENT> results = new List<ATTACHMENT>();
 int pos = 0;
 foreach (int i in id)
            {
               
                var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[pos];
                pos++;

                [...]

                results.Add(attachment);

                [...]
   }
```

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).